# Why I can't connect to evil AP, created by a fluxion in non-Kali Linux distributive?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, dhcp, isc-dhcpd, captive-portal

I cloned fluxion with a following command: `git clone https://github.com/FluxionNetwork/fluxion --recursive`

I added the Kali Linux repositories to my distribution, installed all the necessary programs (listed in the fluxion requirements list). The program works.

I successfully receive a handshake and want to launch an evil twin attack on the interest AP. I launch it. 5 xterm windows are opened. Everything should work, I see my point in the list of detected access points, but I can not connect to it. Finally, timeout deauthentication is triggered and the client disconnects from the evil twin.

**What could be the problem and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem happened with the dhcp server (the 6th window, which opens and immediately serves). The client is simply not given an IP.

The problem may lie in the security mechanics of the distribution you are using. For example, in `apparmor` and SELinux. In my case, it all came down to apparmor.

I found out that the dhcpd daemon cannot access the config file located in the `/tmp/fluxspace/` folder. He also needed something in the `/var/` folder.

To verify that the problem is in apparmor, run the command: `dmesg | grep dhcp`.
If the output contains the line `apparmor="DENIED"`, then the problem is in apparmor.

There are 2 solutions to the problem:

1. "the Kali Linux approach": just disable apparmor. This can be done with the command `sudo systemctl disable apparmor`. Then you need to reboot. This will completely disable apparmor on your system (for all programs).
2. "less destructive approach": if you don't want to disable the apparmor daemon (which is probably correct if it was initially active), you can change the server dhcp profile for it. To do this, open the file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd` with any convenient editor. If you scroll through this file, you will see lines like `/usr/lib/something/* r,`. You will need to insert 4 lines next to them:

```
/tmp/* rw,
/tmp/** rw,
/var/* rw,
/var/** rw,
```

After that, you need to save the changes and either restart the computer or reload the apparmor profile with the command `sudo service apparmor reload`.

The fluxion access point should then work properly.

P.S. In fact, the changes to the dhcp profile I proposed can be made much more stringent without consequences for fluxion. I made the settings with an eye to the future - if I need to use dhcp with another program from the Kali repository so that there is probably no need to edit the apparmor profile file for dhcp again. You can read more [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AppArmor#Understanding_profiles).